# Listening understanding problems when something is said "out-of-context"

Tags: british-english, speech

I have studied in UK since I was 15. I have now been here for around 8 years. I have never noticed that I have any issues with language until I started working full-time. I am very used to academic language, so on the meetings at work I can follow what is being said because there is a "theme" of the discussion so to say.

But I have noticed that it is quite hard for me (most of the time) to interpret what is being said if it is being said out of context, for example, if someone cracks a joke, or if someone enters the room and says something. In these circumstances, I find it difficult to understand what is being said and have to ask to repeat again, and when they do I can understand them no problem. I was wondering if anyone is perhaps aware of some good listening resources out there on the web that can train the sort of social setting talking/listening skills? Is anyone also aware of some resources that list some of the more used slang English words?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48464/discussion-on-question-by-i-squared-keep-it-real-listening-understanding-probl).

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch more soap operas such as most obviously Eastenders or Hollyoaks or Coronation Street or even Neighbours… particularly if you can find them with subtitles.

Comment: I was thinking of Eastenders but just from a minute of watching it I found it extremely boring

Comment: Luckily for you there are any number of soapy sows around that have nothing better to do than serve as listening resources that can train the sort of social setting talking/listening skills.

If you really did find anything boring just from a minute of watching it - particularly if you are equating “talking/listening skills” - then are you sure you’re not just hard of hearing?

If it’s really anything like just a minute of watching - even five minutes - then it shouldn’t much matter whether it’s ’stenders or the results from a sport you don’t like in a language you don’t speak, …

Comment: I like science and I constantly study maths/programming.. and I find watching anything other than documentaries or some newly released movies - a waste of time. But clearly, in my case, it probably isn't, since it will allow me to communicate better. Thanks

Comment: Then try The Big Bang Theory, for one…

Comment: Oh yes, I have heard of it! Good point